# how to split an json integer key to get year and month

Tags: json

```
   I have a js object in json format, 
"monthly_sal":{
    "2012_08":"421",
    "2012_09":"332",
    "2012_10":"332"
},
```

I would like to access the 2012_08 as year 2012 and month 08, how can i do it on the key. based on this i need to fill the table with its data respectively. I have teh code to split it but not sure how i can apply the same to the json object keys and iterate through the complete object

```
  var number = 2012_08;
   var splitstring = number.toString().split('_');
   var years = splitstring[0];
   var months = splitstring[1];
   alert(years + ' years,' + months + ' months');​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `for i`n to iterate over the keys, and [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to get numbers from the two parts of the key.

```
for (var key in monthly_sal) {
   var tokens = key.split('_');
   var years = parseInt(tokens[0], 10);
   var months = parseInt(tokens[1], 10);
   alert(years + ' years,' + months + ' months' + ' => ' + monthly_sal[key]);​
}
```